# Add another field date resigned when I change the status of employee to terminated or resigned

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I had some troubles in javascript and front-end development in updating the employee status of each employee. When the employee status is terminated or resigned it will auto add another input field below of the date the employee has been terminated or resigned. If the employee is still not resigned or terminated it will not display anything or nothing will change. I really don't know on how the logic works and how to write the code.
So here's my code in html and php fetching the data of the status of employee:

```
<select class="form-control" id="status" name="status" style="height: 5%" required="">
<option <?php if ($rows['status'] == 'REGULAR EMPLOYEE' ) {echo 'selected'; }?> value="REGULAR EMPLOYEE"> REGULAR EMPLOYEE </option>
<option <?php if ($rows['status'] == 'CONTRACTUAL' ) {echo 'selected'; }?> value="CONTRACTUAL"> CONTRACTUAL </option>
<option <?php if ($rows['status'] == 'PROBATIONARY' ) {echo 'selected'; }?> value="PROBATIONARY"> PROBATIONARY </option>
<option <?php if ($rows['status'] == 'TERMINATED' ) {echo 'selected'; }?> value="TERMINATED"> TERMINATED </option>
<option <?php if ($rows['status'] == 'RESIGNED' ) {echo 'selected'; }?> value="RESIGNED"> RESIGNED </option>
</select>
```

When they select terminated or resigned it will auto display another field below like:

```
<label>Date Terminated</label>
<input type="date">

or

<label>Date Resigned</label>
<input type="date">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an hidden date field, and show/hide it based on the `select` value change.

```js
$("#status").on("change", function(){
  if( $(this).val() == "TERMINATED" || $(this).val() == "RESIGNED" ){
    $(".dateEnd").show(200);
  }else{
    $(".dateEnd").hide(200);
  }
});
```

```css
.dateEnd{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" id="status" name="status" style="height: 5%" required="">
  <option  value="REGULAR EMPLOYEE"> REGULAR EMPLOYEE </option>
  <option  value="CONTRACTUAL"> CONTRACTUAL </option>
  <option  value="PROBATIONARY"> PROBATIONARY </option>
  <option  value="TERMINATED"> TERMINATED </option>
  <option  value="RESIGNED"> RESIGNED </option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="date" class="dateEnd">
```